# OPENSSL_ALGORITHM_DEFINES no longer supported

Tags: linux, debian, openssl

I am trying to compile mosquitto_auth_plugin. During the compilation i get openssl error:

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h:18:3: error: #error OPENSSL_ALGORITHM_DEFINES no longer supported # error OPENSSL_ALGORITHM_DEFINES no longer supported
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: my Debian linux version is: `4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The package is available for debian stretch `apt install mosquitto-auth-plugin`. You don't need to compile.